# OpenERP: Is it possible to update records defined under the XML tag <data noupdate="1"></data>?

Tags: xml, odoo, openerp-7

I have accidentally deleted all the records in mail.messages.subtype. So when I try to send mail from sale order, it shows error as mandatory field is not set correctly. When I checked the files I found that records to mail.message.subtypes were defined under then xml tag `<data noupdate="1"></data>`. So is it possible to update these files again so that these records are created again.

I tried that by using -i all option. But it shows unique key constraint error in mail alias. Is there any way only to update the records defined under mail.message.subtype

Comment: you can update module by using -i  (init) that may help

Comment: I tried that by using -i all option. But it shows unique key contraint error in mail alias.

Comment: Why can't you change it for noupdate="0" for a while?

Comment: Thats the same thing using -i all option. Then the constraint error came up

Answer (score 0):

Create new database or use other existing database

Then export mail_message_typem as csv

Import  the csv in the db of same table which is  having problem

This  will make work

May be this is a  temporary fix

Raise a bug in launchpad with scenario.

Comment: Now I have created a temporary fix by making a module with an xml file contain all the records of mail.message.subtype with xml id of the original one.

Comment: but its not an openerp bug.